# Togetherness - Enigmatic Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, cipher, music

[image: Togetherness]

Clues:

43516 27692 9890 49450 25714 1___ 45494 29670 9890 35604

---

1___

Instructions: Fill-in the Blank

_ _ _ _ a  _ _ _ _

Comment: Is it mandatory for a puzzle to be in text?

Comment: @FlorianF [No](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you

> CHAKA KHAN

Reasoning:

> This looks like a fraction; let's try dividing the top by the bottom.

> There are 2 '9890's; could be 'E'? 9890/5=1978, which is a year within the last century... promising.
>  43516/1978=22=V; looks like we are on track.
>  Continuing: 43516=V, 27692=N, 9890=E, 49450=Y, 25714=M, 1978=A, 45494=W, ?, 29670=O, 9890=E,35604=R

Giving:

> V N E Y M A W O E R

> After a lot of searching and anagramming, I stumbled across the following anagram:
>
>          E V E R Y W O M A N

> A search reveals that according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27m_Every_Woman:
>  ""I'm Every Woman" is a song by American singer Chaka Khan, released as her debut solo single from her first album, Chaka (**1978**)."
>  1978 matches the year we were looking for, and the singer's name, CHAKA KHAN,  fits the final blanks, so our answer is found!

Comment: Feedback: all was good, though I would recommend a title that is either more interesting, useful, or unique. For example, in this multi-step puzzle, a title like "All them girls" would help clue that step 2 is on track, as well as be more memorable than "Who is that" and your name.